# changing the position of ImageView dynamically in android

Tags: android, layoutparams

all

I need to change the position of a ImageView dynamically and iam using the following code

```
int x=100,y=100;
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams mparam = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams((int)(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT),(int)(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    mparam.topMargin=x;
    mparam.leftMargin=y;
    ball.setLayoutParams(mparam);
    x+=100;
    y+=100;
```

but i didnt get any change.

Is it possible? and How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call setPadding on your View. So, in your code (which by the way you should put in a code block!), just add a call to this method:

```
int x=100,y=100; 
LayoutParams mparam = new LayoutParams((int)(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT),(int) (LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
ball.setLayoutParams(mparam); 
ball.setPadding(x,y,0,0);

x+=100; y+=100;
ball.setPadding(x,y,0,0);
```

Comment: Ah I see in some other posts, setPadding doesn't work somehow.. Another possibility (I think) is changing your LayoutParams again after giving them to the ball and then give it to the ball a second time..

Answer (score 4):

You change margin, but not its position and, it seems, it's not a good solution.
Try to use method `View.layout(int, int, int, int)`
[Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#layout%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) says:

```
public void layout (int l, int t, int r, int b)

Since: API Level 1
Assign a size and position to a view and all of its descendants
This is the second phase of the layout mechanism. (The first is measuring). 
In this phase, each parent calls layout on all of its children to position them. 
This is typically done using the child measurements that were stored in 
the measure pass(). Derived classes should not override this method. Derived 
classes with children should override onLayout. In that method, they should call 
layout on each of their children.

Parameters

l   Left position, relative to parent
t   Top position, relative to parent
r   Right position, relative to parent
b   Bottom position, relative to parent
```

Comment: agreed with @GrigoryKalabin that this is a hack, but Grigory's solution is not working... call it this way: ball.layout( iLeft, iTop, iRight, iBottom);