# Set the position of text view in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, margins

this is my xml file,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:background="@color/white" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/datetitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    />

<ImageView
  android:id="@+id/meetingline"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
  android:src="@drawable/meetingline"
  android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
  android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/datetitle"
  android:visibility="gone" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

and this is code in java..

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)  mViewHolder.startDate.getLayoutParams();
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams paramsImage = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) imgView.
   double conversion = minute*2.7;
   int topmargin = (int)conversion;
  // params.setMargins(0,topmargin,0,0);
   params.topMargin = topmargin;
   paramsImage.topMargin = topmargin+15;
       SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a");
       String date = df.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
       if(hour == myList.get(position).getPosition())
       {
           mViewHolder.startDate.setLayoutParams(params);
           mViewHolder.startDate.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
           mViewHolder.startDate =detail(convertView, R.id.datetitle, date);
           if(imgView != null)
               imgView.setLayoutParams(paramsImage);
               imgView.setVisibility(1);
                imgView.bringToFront();
       }
       else{
           params.topMargin=0;
           mViewHolder.startDate.setLayoutParams(params);
           mViewHolder.startDate.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
           imgView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
       }
```

what i am doing is i am setting the textview and image position in relative layout by setting their top margin, but it is not working right there is something going wrong, its extending the the row body, you can see the body of 4 in image i have attached with this post, please guide me how to set the position of textview and image view by not extending the body of row, and guide me what i am doing wrong by which it extends the body.[image]

Comment: You must use LayoutParams and I think [This][1] link will help you.



  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6607190/changing-the-position-of-imageview-dynamically-in-android

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Are you sure that cannot be done just using xml?

Comment: use linear layouts.using weights you can do it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
TextView widget = new TextView(screenContext);
widget.setText("Label");
widget.setLayoutParams(newAbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(width,height,calculatedX,calculatedY));
```